# Is it possible to get the points in a third party Google Map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'd like to get the latitude/longitude of all the points in a map I did not create (e.g. [this one](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&msid=215190805617188643093.0004d5896c687a88e3c01&hl=en&ie=UTF8&ll=6.248301,-75.578534&spn=0.122734,0.047207&t=m&iwloc=0004d58973994e7174f52&output=embed)). Is it possible to get this information using the Google Maps API directly? I know that for that specific example I can find the `markers` object in the page and then fetch the data but I'd rather not rely on HTML parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link you provided is actually not a Google Maps API application. It is a shared map via [Google Maps](https://maps.google.ca/) - which has nothing to do with the javascript API. If you see the end of the URL you'll see the parameter `&output=embed`. Remove that from the URL and it should take you to the original map created on Google Maps itself, in here you can export the points via the KML download link.